django: разбить форму на две независящие друг от друга
Как разбить форму на две независящие друг от друга формы с выводом на одной веб странице и с сохранением данных пользователя в файл output.txt?
views.py
def feedback(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FeedBackForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user_input_data(form)
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            error = 'Введите корректные данные'
    form = FeedBackForm()
    return render(request, 'firstsite/feedback.html', {'form': form, 'error': error})        

def user_input_data(form):
    with open('output.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write('Email:' + form.cleaned_data['email'] + '\n')
        file.write('Phone:' + form.cleaned_data['phone'] + '\n')  

forms.py
from django import forms from .models import FeedBack

class FeedBackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FeedBack
        fields = ['email', 'phone']  

models.py
class FeedBack(models.Model):
    '''форма обратной связи'''
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Форма обратной связи'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Форма обратной связи'


как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.

Вечер добрый. Прошу прощение за корявость.

вопрос непонятен. на какие две формы вы хотите разбить?

Email_form и phone_form. Что бы они были независимы друг от друга. Выводились на одной веб странице и вводимые данные чтобы сохранялись в файл output.txt
